# Why AndEngine's CollisionHandler produces multiple events in one collision?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, andengine

I am writing a GameActivity of a **swinging pendulum** (in AndEngine).

While applying `CollisionHandler`, this will produce a **series of collision events** in the instead of one?? Actually, I'd like it is executed **once only** when sprites collide.

**My case**: when the **`movingBall`** collides with the **`mLeftWall`**, it called **`5 times`** of **`onCollision()`**; It was abnormal, I expected only one time.

Should I use `ContactListener` instead and register with `PhysicsWorld`? Here's my Code:

**MyGameActivity.java:**

```
/** List of objects to check collision of any animating objects. E.g: walls  */
private ArrayList<IShape> mCollidingTargetList = new ArrayList<IShape>();

/** user-defined collision handler */
PendulumCollisionCallback collideActionCallback = new PendulumCollisionCallback();

@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() 
{
    final Scene scene = super.onCreateScene();

    final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();

    //Create walls
    mWallLeft = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, mCameraHeight, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    mWallRight = new Rectangle(mCameraWidth - 2, 0, 2, mCameraHeight, vertexBufferObjectManager);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhyscisWorld, mWallLeft, BodyType.StaticBody, mWallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhyscisWorld, mWallRight, BodyType.StaticBody, mWallFixtureDef);
    scene.attachChild(mWallLeft);
    scene.attachChild(mWallRight);

    //Create movingBall - the pendulum ball
    final AnimatedSprite movingBall = new AnimatedSprite(mCenterX, mCenterY, this.mCircleFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    final Body ballBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, movingBall, BodyType.DynamicBody, mObjectFixtureDef);
    movingBall.setUserData(ballBody); // for getting the body attached with UI

    //..... Stuff to create anchorBody and RevoluteJoint with the movingBall

    //list of bodies where sprites collide
    this.mCollidingTargetList.add(mWallLeft);
    this.mCollidingTargetList.add(mWallRight);

    //Manage user-defined collision handler: movingBall collides with walls
    CollisionHandler pendulumCollideHandler = new CollisionHandler(collideActionCallback, movingBall, mCollidingTargetList);
    scene.registerUpdateHandler(pendulumCollideHandler);

    return scene;
}
```

**PendulumCollisionCallback.java:**

```
public class PendulumCollisionCallback implements ICollisionCallback
{
    public PendulumCollisionCallback()
    { }

    /**
     * @param animatedShape
     *      Entity to check collision with other targets
     * @param pTargetShape
     *      Target to check the collision
     * @return <code>true</code> to proceed, <code>false</code> to stop further collosion-checks.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCollision(IShape animatedShape, IShape pTargetShape) 
    {
        String pendulPos = String.format("Pendul:x=%f, y=%f", animatedShape.getX(), animatedShape.getY());      
        Log.d("COLLIDE", pendulPos);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. This is because of separated `Physics Handler` and Scene's `UpdateHandler` work sequence.

While `PhysicsWorld` is still controlling body collision, the body is still moving forward for a few frames => so that the position of UI sprite (attached with this body) is in junction with colliding object. During these frames, the `updateHandler` produces collision events by `CallbackHandler`.

The solution is a tricky method of adding **Boolean flag** which is **set** at first colliding and **unset** when finish colliding (though this is not nice).

P/S: my frame rate observed form **`FPSLogger`** is `~88,9 FPS`.